# How to decrypt AES CBC encrypted file only knowing key length

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I have a file that is encrypted using AES CBC. The only thing i know is that the password is 6 characters long and the possible 10 characters it possibly has. This password gets hashed into a 128 bit key.

But since 128 bit key decryption takes litteraly forever how do i decrypt this file?

Comment: Are you sure the password is just hashed, or could a key derivation function be involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate every permutations of the 6 characters out of the 10 possible different characters. Then hash those permutations and compare with the password hash you've got. Shouldn't take more than a second or so. 10 to the 6th power is 1000000 permutations which you can generate in a few ms. The hashing takes the longest time and depending on the algorithm it might take up to a minute but rest assured you'll find the correct permutation (password) in a very short time.

There's no need to "decrypt" the 128-bit hash and literally that would be a waste of time since hashes are designed to be "undecryptable". They are called "one-way-hashes" for a reason.

But you'll still need to know which hash-algorithm is used to hash the password to make this work.

Another approach would be to generate all permutations and simply decrypt the file with each and check if there is some valid data there. However, since it's CBC and you don't know the IV that would also be futile.

Comment: normaly it's an md5 hash but about what you said on comparing with the hash i got, i didn't get a hash of the password...

Comment: So you don't have the hash of the password? Then I misinterpreted your question That makes the only viable solution the second of my suggestions. (Decrypt with every permutations and check if there is some valid data). This will take a lot of time but since the number of keys (passwords) is only one million it is possible. It won't take "literallt forever" but still some time.

Comment: ok thanks for that already, also is there a way to check if the password actualy worked with that limited information or do i have to check for each password?

Comment: Not knowing an IV will only affect the first block (16 bytes) .. the rest would come out OK.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen: No. Since it's CBC mode ALL consecutive blocks are affected. You are referring to ECB mode.

Comment: @StudEH: Only way to check is to look at the decrypted data (plaintext). If it is human readable text you'll easily see that. If it is an image, video or music (jpg, png, avi, mpeg, mp3, etc) there are headers in the data you can confirm. In all you need to know what type of data the plaintext consists of or make educated guesses atleast.

Comment: In decrypt with CBC mode the IV is XOR onto the first block after decrypt .. in second block the first block of the cipher text is used .. take a look at -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_CBC. It's a classic problem to have the first block turn out wierd when the IV is wrong ..

Comment: Yeah my bad. Was thinking of PCBC mode.